# Background image in Html Table for Email Template

Tags: html, css, background-image, html-email, newsletter

i am using  background image in html email template, problem is this

```
<table style="background:url('http://i1298.photobucket.com/albums/ag41/Sikander_Nawaz/images_zpsa0d64d23.jpg')  repeat;

background-size: 100%;
```

but that goes as repeat background ,  instead of  one complete one . and if i  use `no-repeat`
that does not go all around the  table just in  top row its visible in other rows its not visible..  please suggest me how to add it  so that it appears as single background .

**Edit** image repeats like this 
[image]

Comment: Please show your full HTML markup, and try putting together a jsFiddle.

Comment: that is  mentioned how i did add background ..    background:url('http://i1298.photobucket.com/albums/ag41/Sikander_Nawaz/images_zpsa0d64d23.jpg')  repeat;

background-size: 100%; just  please let me know if it is right way

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Put together a jsFiddle and you'll have more luck.

Comment: my question is  how to add background  image in html email   thats it .

Comment: Yes, and that's what your code achieves...

Comment: Try just using repeat-y.

Comment: You might want to use a spell-checker, too.

Comment: @Jeff i want it to be single image stretched all  around as background in table not repeating as attached image

Comment: your going to have to do a 1px by x2k and repeat-y....or something because `background-size: 100%;` will not work on most email clients. as far as gradient check this: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/13/techniques-overcome-poor-css-support-email/

Comment: @Sikander, 9 months later, did you solve your situation? Any helping answers so far?

Answer (score 6):

Well, how to add background image in html email. Asuming your doctype is html 4.

```
<table background="your-image.gif">
```

If you define the **scope of accessibility/visibility** of your html email, it will help others suggest you a better solution.

If your email is going to be only on web browser, then you can use .css.

For all of these clients [[listed on wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_email_clients), the concept of "HTML support" does not mean that they can process the full range of HTML that a web browser can handle. Almost all email readers limit HTML features, either for security reasons, or because of the nature of the interface. CSS and JavaScript can be especially problematic. A number of articles describe these limitations per-email-client.

- http://www.sitepoint.com/code-html-email-newsletters/
- http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_email_clients#General_features
- http://alistapart.com/article/cssemail <-- good tips and advices on html email

Answer (score 4):

Try like below, It will help you on some way...

Fiddle Example : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/127/

**CSS :**

```
.tableBG { position: relative; }
.imgBG {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**HTML Table :**

```
<table class="tableBG" width="300px" height="200px" border="1">
    <tr><td><img class="imgBG" src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo4w.png"/>fhdhd</td><td>dhd</td><td>ddhd</td></tr>
    <tr><td>fhdhd</td><td>dhd</td><td>ddhd</td></tr>
    <tr><td>fhdhd</td><td>dhd</td><td>ddhd</td></tr>
    <tr><td>fhdhd</td><td>dhd</td><td>ddhd</td></tr>
    <tr><td>fhdhd</td><td>dhd</td><td>ddhd</td></tr>
    <tr><td>fhdhd</td><td>dhd</td><td>ddhd</td></tr>
    <tr><td>fhdhd</td><td>dhd</td><td>ddhd</td></tr>
    <tr><td>fhdhd</td><td>dhd</td><td>ddhd</td></tr>
    <tr><td>fhdhd</td><td>dhd</td><td>ddhd</td></tr>
    <tr><td>fhdhd</td><td>dhd</td><td>ddhd</td></tr>
    <tr><td>fhdhd</td><td>dhd</td><td>ddhd</td></tr>
        <tr><td>fhdhd</td><td>dhd</td><td>ddhd</td></tr>
    <tr><td>fhdhd</td><td>dhd</td><td>ddhd</td></tr>
    <tr><td>fhdhd</td><td>dhd</td><td>ddhd</td></tr>
    <tr><td>fhdhd</td><td>dhd</td><td>ddhd</td></tr>    
</table>
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: removing the height 100% and position: absolute makes this more compatible for email use.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really stretch a background image indefinitely, just as with any image, and [`background-size` doesn't work the way you want it to](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp).

Setting `background-size: 100%` isn't what you're looking for.  Try `background-size: cover` if you want it to fit entirely within the parent element.  Beware of pixelation if your image is small and your table is big.

Alternatively, if you simply want the image at the start of every row, put the background on your TR elements.

I think the problem you are likely to encounter is [CSS support in e-mail clients](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).  I'm not sure which clients (if any) support CSS 3 well.  I'm sure you'd be ok for webmail clients, but I'm willing to bet your e-mails will look terrible in Outlook.

Comment: background :cover is not supported in outlook i just cheked

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some more CSS:

```
-webkit-background-size: cover; // Safari Chrome
-moz-background-size: cover; // Firefox
-o-background-size: cover; // Opera
background-size: cover; //newer Browser
```

Comment: and backround-repeat ?should i set it to y or x?

Comment: @Sikander: Neither.  Check the link in my answer for an explanation of background-size: cover;